# Without iterating row by row through a dataframe, which takes ages, how can I check that a number of rows all meet a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration

I want to do the following, but obviously I realise that this kind of iterative method is very slow with large DataFrames, what other solutions are there to this problem?:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    for n in range(1001):
        if df["Close"][(i+n)] > df["MA"][i+n]:
            df["Strategy 1"][i] = "Buy"
```

**What I would expect the code above to do is:**

Sub in **n from 0 to 1,000** into line 3, with an **i of 0**, and then if the condition in line 3 held for each n in the range of 0 to 1,000 then it would go on and carry out the operation in line 4.

After this it would take **i of 1** and then sub in **n from 0 to 1,000** into line 3, and if the condition held for all n in that range then it would carry out line 4.

After this it would take **i of 2** and then sub in **n from 0 to 1,000** into line 3, and if the condition held for all n in that range then it would carry out line 4.

After this it would take **i of 3** and then sub in **n from 0 to 1,000** into line 3, and if the condition held for all n in that range then it would carry out line 4.

**...**  **...**

After this it would take **i of len(df)** and then sub in **n from 0 to 1,000** into line 3, and if the condition held for all n in that range then it would carry out line 4.

**Regardless of if the code presented above does what i'd expect or not, is there a much faster way to compute this for very large multi Gigabyte DataFrames?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me state how I understand your rule. As near as I can tell you are trying to get a value of "Buy" in the "Strategy 1" column of the df only if there are 1000 consecutive cases where `MA` was greater than the `Close` preceding that time. I think you can get that done simply by using a rolling sum on the comparison:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# build some repeatable sample data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'close': np.cumsum(np.random.randn(10000))})
df['MA'] = df['close'].rolling(1000).mean()

# Apply strategy
npoints = 1000

df['Strategy 1'] = float('nan')
buypoints = (df['MA'] > df['close']).rolling(npoints).sum() == npoints
df.loc[buypoints, "Strategy 1"] = "Buy"

# just for visualisation show where the Buys would be
df['Buypoints'] = buypoints*10
df.plot()
```

This comes out like this (with the same seed it should look the same on your machine too)

[image: Sample curves showing buy points]

Comment: This is absolute wizardry. I still need to figure out exactly how the line buypoints = (df['close'] > df['MA']).rolling(npoints).sum() == npoints works, it seems to do exactly what I need but I just don't quite understand it conceptually yet. Thanks for the answer, the only thing is that I wanted to do close>ma not ma>close, but other than that you smashed it dude, thanks!

Comment: @MoonBoi9001 The reasoning is that you evaluate the condition, which is True or False. The `rolling(npoints).sum()` then calculates _how many_ times it was True in the window, because True behaves like 1 and False behaves like 0 when summed. Then you do the `== npoints` to find the places where it was True for the whole window. This is now a boolean array which you can use to index into the original dataframe to access the points where it is True.

Comment: Excellent explanation, marked you as the accepted answer, really helped me out thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using the .apply function would be faster.  For a general example...

```
import pandas as pd

# only required to create the test dataframe in this example
import numpy as np

# create a dataframe for testing using the numpy import above
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,size=(10, )),columns=['A'])

# create a new column based on column 'A' but moving the column 'across and up'
df['NextRow'] = df['A'].shift(-1)

# create a function to do something, anything, and return that thing
def doMyThingINeedToDo(num, numNext):
#     'num' is going to be the value of whatever is in column 'A' per row 
#     as the .apply function runs below and 'numNext' is plus one.
    if num >= 50 and numNext >= 75:
        return 'Yes'
    else:
        return '...No...'

# create a new column called 'NewColumnName' based on the existing column 'A' and apply the
# function above, whatever it does, to the frame per row.
df['NewColumnName'] = df.apply(lambda row : doMyThingINeedToDo(row['A'], row['NextRow']), axis = 1)

# output the frame and notice the new column
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
    A  NextRow NewColumnName
0  67     84.0           Yes
1  84     33.0      ...No...
2  33     59.0      ...No...
3  59     85.0           Yes
4  85     39.0      ...No...
5  39     81.0      ...No...
6  81     76.0           Yes
7  76     83.0           Yes
8  83     60.0      ...No...
9  60      NaN      ...No...
```

The main point is that you can separate what exactly you want to do per row and contain it in a function (that can be tweaked and updated as required) and just call that function for all rows on a frame when required.

Comment: So if I wanted to check that the elements contained in both of column A row 0 and column A row 1 are greater than 1, and if they are then put yes in newcolumnname row 0, how would I do that?

Comment: I've updated the answer for one way you could achieve it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer this is a good solution but also means that my already multi gigabyte database would need to grow even larger, i'm working with 1.4 million rows and over 1000 columns, to implement this solution i'd need to add another 2,500+ columns where an element would be populated in each row of those additional columns, so my database would grow to 25gb+, not something i'm eager to let happen at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you are attempting with only your close data.  Calculating the MA and 1000 conditions on the fly via vectorization. Maybe try this:

```
import numpy as np

ma_window = 1000 
n = 1000 

df['Strategy 1'] = \
    np.where( \
        (df['close'] > df['close'].rolling(window=ma_window).mean()).rolling(window=n).mean() == 1, \
             'buy','')
```

Play around with this and see if it might work for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Iteration is a last resort with Pandas.

The solution you are looking for is coming from numpy:

```
import numpy as np
df["Strategy 1"] = np.where(df["Close"] > df["MA"], "Buy", df["Strategy 1"])
```

Comment: Not sure if it was clear from my question but what I was trying to was check not just that df["Close"][i] > df["MA"][i] but also that df["Close"][i+1] > df["MA"][i+1], df["Close"][i+2] > df["MA"][i+2], df["Close"][i+3] > df["MA"][i+3], ... , df["Close"][i+n] > df["MA"][i+n] then if and only if all of those hold true, then carry out df["Strategy 1"][i] = "Buy"

Comment: @MoonBoi9001 which is what the answer does, maybe this helps: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html, or am I misunderstanding and your logic has a cross-row dependence?  A clear expected input and expected output example would clarify the question quite a bit.